# What is the difference between various MSBuild version properties, such as Version, VersionPrefix, and VersionSuffix?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

Building projects with MSBuild 15 and Microsoft.NET.Sdk allows users to specify half a dozen version properties. What is the difference between each of these and what is the right way to use them?

- Version
- VersionPrefix
- VersionSuffix
- AssemblyVersion
- FileVersion
- PackageVersion

And to be clear, I'm talking about "properties" as MSBuild properties that are defined in the file (as below)

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <Version>1.2.0</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

...or on command line as `msbuild.exe /p:Version=1.2.0`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Also, setting these values explicitly will override the defaults.

**VersionPrefix**

*Format:* major.minor.patch

*Examples:* 14.2.4, 0.1.0, 99.99.99

*Meaning*: The normal part of the semver version number. This is used to determine the beginning of the **Version** value.

*Default:* "1.0.0"

**VersionSuffix**

*Format*: [0-9A-Za-z-.]* (arbitrary string)

*Examples*: alpha, beta, build0123, rc4-build201701, rc.1, rc-1

*Meaning*: The pre-release label of the version number. Used to determine the ending of a **Version** value.

*Default*: (empty)

**Version**

*Format:* major.minor.patch[-prerelease]

*Examples*: 5.3.9-beta, 0.0.1-alpha-01, 0.0.1-alpha.1, 2.0.0

*Meaning*: This property is the most commonly used property in user projects. Other version properties look to this value as a default. It is also used to generate the value of `System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`. The preprelease value is optional.

*Default:* **VersionPrefix** if VersionSuffix is empty. **VersionPrefix-VersionSuffix** if VersionSuffix is *not* empty.

Note: setting **Version** explicitly will override any **VersionPrefix** or **VersionSuffix** settings.

Also, this typically follows SemVer rules. See http://semver.org/ for details

**PackageVersion**

*Format:* major.minor.patch[-prerelease]

*Meaning:* Used to generate the package version when producing a NuGet package from an MSBuild project.

*Default*: matches **Version**

**AssemblyVersion**

*Format:* major.minor.patch.revision

*Examples:* 4.5.6.2, 1.0.0.0

*Meaning:* Used to generate the value of `System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute`. The compiler uses this to determine the final AssemblyVersion value, an essential part of assembly identity. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0

*Default*: matches **Version** without the prerelease label.

**FileVersion**

*Format* major.minor.patch.buildnumber

*Examples*: 1.0.0.43952, 0.1.0.0

*Meaning*: Used to generate the value of `System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute`. This is not required to match AssemblyVersion. It is common to add a build number to this version.

*Default*: matches **AssemblyVersion**

**InformationalVersion**

*Format*: any

*Meaning*: Used to generate the value of `System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute`. This attribute can contain any additional version information.

*Default*: matches **Version**

Comment: This is great. Out of curiosity, where would I find this in Microsoft's documentation?

Comment: I used Message task to try and output these from a msbuild definition and they were not set.  I'm not real clear on in what context these are available.  The only docs I see show them used via reflection from code.  I think might only be available if you're using dotnet cli v2

Comment: This answer ist rewritten and extended at https://andrewlock.net/version-vs-versionsuffix-vs-packageversion-what-do-they-all-mean/

Comment: @natemcmaster Do you happen to know the rational behind all these different knobs?  Something I've found profoundly frustrating is the mismatch between Nuget package versions and assembly versions.  I just don't see the benefit this extra complexity adds.  While your post is very informative, it doesn't cover the WHY.  For a glimpse as to why, readers can go to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-3/ - however, I think this only covers the "SemVer-CD mismatch".  There is also another mismatch I lack the vocabulary words for.

Comment: "Why the mismatch?": My speculation is that the creators of .NET drew inspiration from Windows file versioning (as in winver.h and VERSIONINFO... the 4 parts schema major.minor.patch.build). NuGet, on the other hand, drew inspiration from other package managers like Ruby Gems, Apt-Get, and Maven, which use 3-part versioning (see https://haacked.com/archive/2010/10/06/introducing-nupack-package-manager.aspx/)

Comment: Why so many knobs? Most of knob listed above represents a different aspect of the package, assembly, assembly attributes, or .dll file. The exception: VersionPrefix and VersionSuffix. These were added so it would be easier to hard-code VersionPrefix into your .csproj file while allowing VersionSuffix to be auto-generated by CI or command-line args. E.g. `dotnet pack --version-suffix beta-123`

Comment: Can you kindly explain about the "ApplicationVersion" property as well?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that FileVersion is used by Windows Installer to help decide which file to keep when deploying a file to a location where one already exists.

Comment: what is the equivalent of `dotnet pack --version-suffix beta-123` if someone is using MSBuild, i.e. not a netcore app

Answer (score 9):

I would like to expand on the answer which was already given above to Visual Studio.  If you got here because you were wondering how this all works in Visual Studio 2022 (and earlier), this is a short explanation as I could not find any official docs on the matter.

If you create a .net core Console app, and go to Project Properties, you will see a section "Package --> General" that covers versioning.  It is populated with default values which are shown beneath each element.

Here is a screenshot of one of the elements with it's default value.  So what is "$(VersionPrefix)"?  As discussed above, it is one of the properties that can be set. But note there is no place in the UI to set this, but you can set it directly in the project file by editing it.

[image]

So let's do that now:

[image]

After saving the file, you now see the following:

[image]

But that's not really very useful for a version number.  So lets add a Suffix to the project file.

`<VersionSuffix>5-beta</VersionSuffix>`

But now the version looks like this:

[image]

But that's not really what we want, so lets add a version number to the center:

[image]

And this give us this in the file explorer:

[image]

So, to recap:  The UI is just writing to the Project File.  No magic there.  But how does it get consumed from the project file?  Well, actually, there is a  file being created in the background called .AssemblyInfo.cs. It looks like this:

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("ConsoleApp2")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("Debug")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("2.3.5.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("2.3.5-beta")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("ConsoleApp2")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("ConsoleApp2")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("2.3.5.0")]
```

And that file is being consumed by the compiler when the project is compiled.

If you wanted to, you could skip all of the UI and project files, and just create the AssemblyInfoFile directly. But when you do that, you lose the VersionPrefix and VersionSuffix functionality and you have to do it manually.

Comment: Even if the name is version prefix, you can put a whole version number there, like 1.3.22, if you want. So you don't need to put tha "3" in the UI. Just put it in the prefix.
In fact, int he UI you see $(Version) which is $(VersionPrefix)-$(VersionSuffix). Or only $(VersionPrefix) is ther eis no suffix. The suffix is expected to be something like "beta.1" or "rc2".