# increment numbers in version.props

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, msbuild, asp.net-core-mvc

I have seen version.props file in some open source projects [here](https://github.com/prospa-group/AspNetCoreExtensions/blob/master/version.props) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/build/Versions.props).

The content is the following:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>0.0.1</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix></VersionSuffix>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I understand this has to do with building projects and version numbers, easy.

My question is how can I increase the version numbers?

I have looked at [dotnet cli tools and commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build), didnt see any reference about that.

Can you pleaze give me the codez? I mean , help me understand how I can work this version.props file?

Comment: Build Server should provide build number. (jenkins, bamboo or whatever) You need to call msbuild command with "build number" parameter as described in the following answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183381/1099 As for prefix it should be changed manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is include in each project file : `<Import Project="..\version.props" />` directly or indirectly throught an other import. And version is updated by hand.

But you can also use `dotnet msbuild` with `/p:Version={your version number}`:

```
dotnet msbuild /t:build /p:Version=1.0.0
```

Or with publish target for exemple:

```
dotnet msbuild /t:publish /p:Version=1.0.0
```

Comment: `dotnet msbuil /t:build /p:Version=1.0.0 ` when i run this it does not override version.props file.

Comment: i was hoping that this command override version.props. but it aint.

Comment: no it doesn't but it update the version number of generate lib

Comment: You can use a script update the file, like a powershell script

Comment: I see. again, I was hoping to bind that via jenkins, i guess, i need a script to override that. thanks.

Comment: by the way there is no aqua in mars.